# Как изменить заголвки в CURL

Tags: php, php-curl

**Мне нужно сделать крос доменный запрос что бы обойти CORS, как в курле можно подменить заголовки?**

```
function apiCall($params)
{
    $url = 'https://side/v1/api';
    $ch = curl_init();
    $data = http_build_query($params);
    $getUrl = $url."?".$data;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $getUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 80);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_error($ch)){
        echo 'Request Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    else
    {
        echo $response;
    }

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Обойти CORS? Опишите получше Вашу проблему, а не то, как Вы пытаетесь ее решить.

Comment: Есть сайты который принимают запросы с определенного домена, в основном с того на котором лежат, если кидать запрос с другого сайта например либо с бека то CORS начинает ругатся, мне надо решить эту проблему

Comment: Опять же, что значит начинает ругаться CORS? Вы это не обойдете посылаемыми заголовками, это удаленный сервер проставляет заголовок, который Ваша сторона уже интерпретирует.

Comment: CORS заголовки нужны и важны для клиентской части (JavaScript в браузере). Если вы шлете запросы используя сервер (PHP), то вам они не будут важны.